# Adding extra glyphicons to bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Dear fellow designers/developers

I have created 8 extra glyphicons for my bootstrap website. Uploaded them to icomoon and downloaded them as font, this all works perfect.

I am able to add my font to my CSS and use it in HTML withou any problem, but I want to use the font as extra Glyphicons.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14):

refer to this website which provides the font icons to bootstrap

[Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

download fontawesome here [fontawesome.io](http://fontawesome.io/)

add css file link to your page

```
 <link href='/path/to/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

use css classes mentioned in `font-awesome.css` stating with `'fa-'`

example: `<i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>`

please copy `css` and `fonts` folders to same folder

Comment: Thank's for the link, i've heared about fontawsome, but i can't find anything on their website, could you be more precise?

Answer (score -1):

Steps to use font-Awsome

1. Download [Font-Awsome](http://fontawesome.io/)
2. Extract .zip file
3. after extracting, you will get folder i.e. font-awesome-4.5.0
4. Add this folder by drag and drop to your content or bootstrap folder
5. Add font-awesome.css file as a reference in your web-page

   ```
   <link href="~/Content/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   ```
6. get icons as told by @G Ravinder i.e.

   ```
   <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
   <span class="fa fa-desktop"></span>
   ```

That's all :-)