# bootstrap glyphicon unlock is not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I've table with a column status and possible values for status are 1 and 0.

Now I'm trying to show glyph-icon unlock but it is not at all displaying however glyph-icon lock is working fine.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.5. I don't know why it is not displaying.

when I inspected using google chrome the corresponding icon class is not existed.

So it would be great if someone could provide the content value for unlock

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**simple answer**

Well based on your question I'm guessing you have a set up like this for your glyphicons:

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock'></span>
```

That will show your padlocak correctly, and you want to know why

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-unlock'></span>
```

is not showing. I did some research for you really quick, and on the site's official documentation for bootstrap components http://getbootstrap.com/components/, you'll see a listing of all the usable glyphicons in the bootstrap library, `unlock` is not one of them unfortunately.

**alternative solution**

Fontawesome is a set of icons that with a very large library, and yes your unlock icon is definitely on there. I'm not sure how you go about using all of this but I've found some resource links for you!

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

[Adding extra glyphicons to bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823756/adding-extra-glyphicons-to-bootstrap)

I hope at least some of this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It is because Bootstrap actually only uses the Glyphicon "Halflings" set of icons which does not include the "unlock" icon. You can view the "halflings" here:
http://glyphicons.com/
click on the "halflings" tab.

As stated on the [getbootstrap.com/components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) page:

> Available glyphs Includes over 250 glyphs in font format from the
>   Glyphicon ***Halflings*** set. Glyphicons ***Halflings*** are normally not
>   available for free, but their creator has made them available for
>   Bootstrap free of cost. As a thank you, we only ask that you include a
>   link back to Glyphicons whenever possible.